# How to compare data between two databases using toad data point?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sybase, toad

I have access to two different data bases 1. SQL Server and 2. Sybase using toad data point.

I have the below data:

[image]

What query do I write to compare data between the two databases - given their table_name and Col_name and I only have access to Toad to connect to the databases?

I want to test whether there is same data reflecting under tables and columns for the two databases.